# Accessing Javascript nested functions and objects

Tags: javascript, object, nested, tabulator

I am using Tabulator data grid javascript library, it initiates like this:

```
let grid = new Tabulator("#grid1", {// configuration goes here});
```

As any other Javascript library, Tabulator allows to use various methods like so: grid.setData().

In my project there are tens of grids and I want to organize them better in my Javascript files. I am trying to create a single function/object and put all grid objects inside, then access function/object members to initiate required grid and still be able to access Tabulator methods like grid.setData().

Example:

```
function allGrids() {
    this.grid1 = new Tabulator("#grid1");
    this.grid2 = new Tabulator("#grid2");
    this.grid3 = new Tabulator("#grid1");

    let gridsObj = {
      grid1: this.grid1,
      grid2: this.grid2,
      grid3: this.grid3
    };

    return gridsObj;
}

let grids = new allGrids();

// Access grid1
grids.grid1
// Access grid2
grids.grid2
// Access grid3
grids.grid3
```

I expect it to work like so: grids.grid1, also other Tabulator methods should be accessible to reload/update data like so: grids.grid1.setData().

After placing multiple Tabulator objects inside allGrids function, all three grids are initiated at the same time. How to stop them all automatically executing and make it work only when specific object member is called?

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function allGrids() {
    this.grid1 = () => new Tabulator("#grid1");
    this.grid2 = () => new Tabulator("#grid2");
    this.grid3 = () => new Tabulator("#grid1");

    let gridsObj = {
      grid1: this.grid1,
      grid2: this.grid2,
      grid3: this.grid3
    };

    return gridsObj;
}

let grids = new allGrids();

// Access grid1
grids.grid1()
// Access grid2
grids.grid2()
// Access grid3
grids.grid3()
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing a tiny, but important thing :)

Comment: Is there any alternative method for "= () =>"?

Comment: @LifeIsShort sure: `= function() { return new Tabulator("#selector"); }` - if that was the question. But I'm still not sure why you need that `allGrids` constructor at all... :| Seems to me that you just need a sligleton Object instead. No function needed.

Comment: Thank you! The reason I need it, because I am working on dynamic project where content is loaded with javascript. Grids do not exist on page load, they are initiated dynamically with javascript and I found the easiest way to initiate grids when needed, is by using such constructor. Otherwise I get lots of errors because grid objects are not present on the page and so on...